# How to disable the background overlay in Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Unfortunately I am NOT a coder, but a designer, and I have a premium Wordpress theme called SIRIUS which has a fancy box overlay over the background image and I want to disable it. How do I do that?

I have tried adding custom CSS code to change the opacity of the overlay to "0" but that didn't work. I have tried whatever I could find from Google searches.

```
//Disable overlay helper
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers:  {
        overlay : null
    }
});
```

All I am trying to do is have my background image to appear on my Wordpress site, but I do not want the themes forced overlay, and want it disabled.

Comment: It'd be easier to help if we could see your site - can you share the URL?

Comment: Is it possible for me to direct message you somehow, Im new to stack overflow and have never used it either, maybe I can email you the login credentials as the site is currently hidden from public view using an "under construction" Wordpress plugin. Thanks so much. Dino (at) gmail (dot) com

Comment: Are you sure that email address is correct..?

Comment: My sincerest apologies. I actually meant to write: Dinovdm (at) gmail (dot) com. Sorry about that. I wasn't focussing.

Comment: For start, you should tell at least what version you are using. That snippet is for v2, but for v3 you use CSS to customize overlay, for example, `.fancybox-bg { color: transparent;  }`

Comment: Thank you @Janis, I appreciate your feedback, I am using version v2.1.4 but user7290573 helped me to resolve my issue, and for all of your help I am truly grateful. As a graphic designer code freaks me out. You are all very smart people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the HTML, a simple CSS rule was all that was needed:

```
.backstretch img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Edit:** just to clarify, this CSS applies to the "Sirius" WordPress theme, not FancyBox.

Comment: Thank you so much @user7290573 you have honestly made my day and weekend. You have no idea how I was struggling to find this solution. I appreciate your help very much. How do I mark this issue as resolved?